# Event loop error in asyncio Lock when instantiated multiple times

Tags: python, locking, python-asyncio

I'm running into some strange errors with initialising Locks and running asynchronous code. Suppose we had a class to use with some resource protected by a lock.

```
import asyncio

class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = asyncio.Lock()

    async def foo(self):
        async with self.lock:
            return 'foo'

def async_foo():
    c = C()
    asyncio.run(c.foo())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    async_foo()
    async_foo()
```

This throws an error when run. It occurs on lock initialisation in `init`.

> RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread'.

So duplicating the `asyncio.run` call in the function does not have this effect. It seems that the object needs to be initialised multiple times. It is also not enough to instantiate multiple locks in a single constructor. So perhaps it has something to do with the event loops state after `asyncio.run` is called.

What is going on? And how could I modify this code to work? Let me also clarify a bit, the instance is created outside `asyncio.run` and async functions for a reason. I'd like for it to be usable elsewhere too. If that makes a difference.

Alternatively, can `threading.Lock` be used for async things also? It would have the added benefit of being thread-safe, which `asyncio.Lock` reportedly is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is going on?

- When async object is created (`asyncio.Lock()`) it is attached to [current](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.set_event_loop) event loop and can only be used with it
- Main thread have some default current event loop (but other threads you create won't have default event loop)
- `asyncio.run()` internally creates new event loop, set it current and close it after finished

So you're trying to use lock with event loop other than one it was attached to on creation. It leads to errors.

> And how could I modify this code to work?

Ideal solution is following:

```
import asyncio


async def main():
    # all your code is here


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

This will guarantee that every async object created is attached to proper event loop `asyncio.run` has created.

Running event loop (inside `asyncio.run`) is meant to be global "entry point" of your async program.

> I'd like for it to be usable elsewhere too.

You're able to create an object outside `asyncio.run`, but then you should you should move creating async object from `__init__` somewhere elsewhere **so that `asyncio.Lock()` wouldn't be created until asyncio.run() is called**.

> Alternatively, can threading.Lock be used for async things also?

[No](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43882301/1113207), it is used to work with threads, while asyncio operates coroutines inside a single thread (usually).

> It would have the added benefit of being thread-safe, which asyncio.Lock reportedly is not.

In `asyncio` you usually don't need threads other than main. There're still [some reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22414756/1113207) to do it, but thread-unsafety of `asyncio.Lock` shouldn't be an issue.

---

Consider reading following links. It may help to comprehend a situation better:

- [why we need asyncio/threads at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45435807/1113207)
- [When should I write asynchronous code instead of synchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33399896/1113207)

Comment: Thank you! The first part clarifies things a lot. But, is using threading completely out of the question? I mean, yes, it is intended for multiple threads, but why not a single thread? If a resource is to be protected, surely a more generic lock is enough for a specific situation. If I acquire it, will it not protect the resource from other concurrent calls? Or is it the coroutine nature that prevents async from working right in that situation? - Ah, I think the second answer of the question you linked addresses that issue.